# Missing Format Text when editing page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

My Format text field/tab is missing when I want to edit my pages. I am using SP2013

[image]

Comment: your description is not detail enough. please tell in detail from the first you click "Edit Page" until the point you noticed the Format Text is missing. FYI, when your cursor is not on the editable text section, Format Text tab will gone missing & vice versa.

Comment: I am missinging entire FORMAT TEXT tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I reverted to previous version of my page and the `FORMAT TEXT` option in top ribbon showed up again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert **WebPart - Content Editor**. In this WP you can format text or have cursor in the blank web-part place. Format text will be displayed immediately.